# How to access an endpoint directly with Keycloak authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have problems to access endpoints directly with Keycloak authentication (with role based access). For example, I can open swagger, give it an access token, and then access the endpoints. I can do this also with postman, making a request with the token in the Authorization header.

I assumed when I make a request in my browser to an endpoint (ex: https://localhost:port/test/eval/getQuestions), after authentication Keycloak would send the access token. But I don't see any Authorization header, where it should be setted... It works if I don't do role based access, because the roles are taked from the access token.

Are there any settings that I might be missed? I am using Spring Boot 3.

Here is my security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${eval.required.role.name}")
    private String requiredRoleName;


    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler, Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter, ServerProperties serverProperties) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);

        // If SSL enabled, disable http (https only)
        if (serverProperties.getSsl() != null && serverProperties.getSsl().isEnabled()) {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        } else {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
        }

        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        delegate.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");

        CsrfTokenRequestHandler requestHandler = delegate::handle;

        http.authorizeRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").authenticated();
            auth.requestMatchers("/**").hasAuthority(requiredRoleName); //if I don't check the roles, I get the result in the browser. So without this line it works fine
            auth.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        });
       
 
       http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        http.oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        // This is a converter for roles, as embedded in the JWT by a Keycloak server
        return jwt -> {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            return realmRoles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    }

}
```

Comment: When using the browser, how are you authenticating against keycloak?

Comment: I enter the url of the endpoint in the browser and it redirects me to the keycloack login page. If the authorization is not given based on roles, the endpoint is called and I receive the result. If the roles are checked, I get 403. The user has the role, and it works on postman where I set the token in the Authorization header....

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing client and resource server configuration in the same security filter chain. That won't work:

- with `http.oauth2Login()`, you ask for requests to be secured with sessions (not bearer tokens)
- with `http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()`, you ask for requests to be secured with JWT bearer access token (not sessions)

The second option requires your browser to be an OAuth2 client, which it isn't out of the box: it does not know of to handle OAuth2 flows, how to store tokens, how to authorize requests, (and it only send GET requests).

To have your browser be a proper OAuth2 client (like Postman or Swagger), you'll need:

- a framework to send REST requests (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE exchanging more than just HTML). Angular, React and Vue are the most famous
- an OAuth2 client lib to handle OAuth2 flows (fetch tokens from the authorization server), store this tokens and then authorize requests (position the Authorization header). [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) is a sample of such a lib for Angular applications.

See this other answer I wrote for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829647/619830

Comment: Thank you, I read your answer and your tutorials, but just to be sure: If I want to authenticate against Keycloak and use the access token for authorizations, somehow the front-end side has to put the token in the Authorization header so that I can use it on the back-end. Right? And that would be the only way to have Role Based Access

Comment: Don't skip the OAuth2 essentials section in the tutorials... Access control (whatever based) should be based on user claims (inside a JWT or in the introspection response)

Comment: The access token is set in the Authorization header by the **OAuth2 client**. This can be the front-end itself or a Middleware maintaining sessions for the front-end, handling OAuth2 flows, storing tokens in session and replacing session cookie with access-token when forwarding a request from the front-end to an OAuth2 resource server.**in the second case, there is no token in the front end**