# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Authenticating Azure AD token to authorize some endpoints/controllers

Security configuration

Compilation Error

```
Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenResolver
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private TokenFilter tokenFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/api/authenticate/username")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter());
    }

}
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenResolver` looks like a missing runtime dependency

Comment: Also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829647/18157), which I found by searching for the NoClassDefFoundError message text.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Build your application through your preferred build tool manager (ex. Gradle), then check back again, if the issue still persists it might miss a dependency in the pom.xml (if maven) or build.gradle (if gradle) file.

Answer (score 0):

dependency missing:

1. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server
2. org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose

encountered the same problem, add these two dependecy fix the problem for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).