# Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' using oauth2ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new in Spring securiy, and I stacked into securityFilterChain using oauth2ResourceServer with this error

ERROR 18552 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path
> resource [com/example/scratch/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]:
> Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception
> is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenResolver
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:824)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:777)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]

Below the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xsuaa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And the class for the security configuration:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.antMatchers( "/welcome").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/user")
                        .hasAuthority("Readscratch")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter()));
        return http.getOrBuild();
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74939220/classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-security-oauth2-server-resource-web) helping?

Comment: I believe you're missing a dependency:

<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>

Comment: @lane.maxwell is right, you are missing the boot starter for resource servers. If you are starting with OAuth2, you might find [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) useful